# How do you word-wrap react-jsx source code?

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I want to word-wrap my JSX code at a given right margin, but the JSX compilation process eats the whitespace.

One way to fix this is by interpolating a whitespace literal like below.

```
<Modal.Body>
  <h4>You logged in as <b>{this.state.authState.email}</b>{" "}
    at {this.state.authState.issueDate.toLocaleString()}</h4>
  <h4>Your log in session expired at{" "}
    {this.state.authState.expiryDate.toLocaleString()}</h4>
</Modal.Body>
```

It's a bit ugly to read and re-wrapping the lines as text is edited will be a pain.  Are there any other ways to do word-wrapping in JSX source code?